# ROS Answers SE migration: irobot create

Tags: ros, irobot-create, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all , i am tending to buy irobot create for my application ,, but my country work on 220 volt Not 110 volt ,, So i suggest to buy it and use Transformer to Convert the volt
but i fear of this to be not safe to the irobot ,,

any one here worked with irobot create Using external transformer ??

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51036/irobot-create/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-12-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-12-27**:
@salma I came across a good electrician and he made a step-down appliance into my irobot adapter/charger ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just checked the transformer. It states that you need 22V and at least 1.25A. It should be possible to find a transformer (maybe from a laptop) which can get close enough to 22V and 1.25A should not be a problem either

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1